# android Manage Multiple screen sizes using dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

My first problem is, I am developing Android application where I want to manage the different screen sizes and display the data according to screen size. I have googled for it. Most of the people are saying to create the layout folder for different screen sizes(ex. layout-sw320, layout-sw480 etc..).

So I came up with another thought that I want to create only One layout, and create multiple dimens.xml file(ex. dimens-sw320.xml, dimens-sw480.xml etc..).

I created dimens.xml files like this four different widths(320dp, 480dp, 600dp, 720dp). But When I give dimensions for a textview It's not exactly displaying the ouput according to screen size. Can anyone here explain which dp size used for which screen size. Any help would be grateful.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: i have come up with this idea as well. would anyone comment on which one is better? (in terms of performance and code maintainability) multiple layout.xml or multiple dimens.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `Resource Directory` for each category you want.

`Project --> app --> res --> Right Click --> Add Resource Directory` and select all the qualifiers you need.

For istance place the `dimen.xml` related to `720dp` in `values-w720dp` directory.

Comment: Thanks Sid, I have created values folders like you said.. I want to know which screen size uses which values folder.. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Checkout the reference here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html